# Linux command piping in openssl to use string input

Tags: linux, shell, openssl, pipe

I have a shell script where a file path `$path` have some text which I encrypt as below and it works:

`content_sha256="$(openssl dgst -binary -sha256 < $path | openssl enc -e -base64)";`

The value of variable `content_sha256` works correctly.

Now, I have a string `$body` which I want to encrypt. I am trying below but it gives me entirely different result.

`content_sha256="$(echo $body | openssl dgst -sha256 | openssl enc -e -base64)";`

Am I piping something wrong or option for `openssl` should be different?

Comment: `echo` adds a newline after the text. try `echo -n $body`

Comment: Tried without -n also. No success.

Comment: **it's the `-binary`.** Your first command has `dgst` with `-binary` and the second doesn't, so it outputs totally different output resullting in totally different base64.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Correct answer below
`content_sha256="$(echo $body | openssl dgst -binary -sha256 | openssl enc -e -base64)";`

Points to note:

1. Include `-binary` option.
2. Instead of redirection of file content as input, use `echo $body` with pipe .